# Typeof dynamic object in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to now if this kind of black magic is possible in typescript.

In **test.dictionary.ts**

```
export const dictionary = {
    text_to_translate: {
        en: 'Text to translate',
        fr: 'Texte à traduire'
    }
};
```

In **app.dictionary.ts**

```
export const appDictionary = {
    APP_POINTER: {
        header: {
            en: 'header',
            fr: 'entête'
        }
    }
    
};
```

After dictionary files has been defined i want to merge them in one object:

In **util.ts**

```
let config = {};

loadWithReplace(_config: Config): void {
    config = {...config, ..._config};
}
```

Everything looks fine until i trying to access property keys from **util.ts** `config`.

In **app.component.ts**

[image]

Don't know if the rest codebase details are necessary, i'll just keep things simple for now.
Is it possible with typescript to achieve this behaviour?

UPD:
[Minimal reproduction example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/base-angular-12-app-pey7sf?file=src%2Fapp%2Futil.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.dictionary.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: [Please replace/supplement images of code/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218).  Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates your issue, and only your issue, when pasted into an IDE.  Right now `loadWithReplace` is... what, a method with no surrounding class?  A syntactically invalid function declaration?  What type is `Config`?

Comment: show `Config` definition at least

Comment: @jcalz
I added link to stackblitz example

Answer (score 0):

Typescript is structurally typed, not nominally typed. It is also dependent on factors knowable at compile-time, not at runtime.

- `loadWithReplace(...)` is a function that runs at runtime (and it's side-effects are unknowable, since the function isn't pure).
- `let config = {}` could literally be anything at runtime (and by definition is literally any object and can be changed to anything else).

As such, we can only do this sort of dynamic type merging (with strict type features) when we explicitly know the previous value of the config and the new value. So we need the parameters to include the previous value, and new value. We can use generics to get an intersected return value.

```js
export function loadWithReplace<T, N extends Config>(oldConfig: T, newConfig: N): Readonly<T> & Readonly<N> {
  return {...oldConfig, ...newConfig} as T & N
}
```

Then we can do stuff like this

```js
const mergeObjects = loadWithReplace({}, {foo: {en: 'bar', fr: 'bàr'}})

console.log(mergeObjects.foo.en)
console.log(mergeObjects.foo.fr)

const mergeDeeper = loadWithReplace(mergeObjects, {baz: {en: 'bar', fr: 'bar'}})

console.log(mergeDeeper.baz.en)
console.log(mergeDeeper.baz.fr)
```

Otherwise, what you're doing (ie. a super dynamic type) kind of goes against the point of TS (how do we effectively typeguard it?, how can we know the type ahead of time?; we can't...)

Otherwise seek to validate your types using control flow/assertions if they really are this dynamic.

The best you can do for a type like this is just to set the config explicitly as well

```js
let config: Config = {}
```

[See Demos on TS Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wRGX1N)